# ruby Test::Unit Command line options?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

When running tests in Ruby's unit::test framework, is there a really easy way to specify, from the command-line, that only one test should be run (that is, specify the test class and test member variable)? If not, is there another framework that has this feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ruby /path/to/foo_test.rb --name test_should_do_something_really_spiffy
```

That will call the test defined by the method `test_should_do_something_really_spiffy` in that file.

EDIT: That's for the `Test::Unit` framework that most ruby tests are written with.  I am assuming you meant the same.

Comment: Is "should_do_something_really_spiffy" a method of the subclass of test::unit?

Comment: Yes.  Note that Test::Unit is being phased out and replaced by "minitest" but it retains the same API.

Comment: you can also use pattern as a --name argument and use -n switch for short; for example: -n /really_spiffy/

Answer (score 5):

If you have the full `Test::Unit` framework, you can do

```
ruby /path/to/foo_test.rb --help
```

to get the command line options. I don't think it works if you just have the minitest version though.