# How can I test only a method with Ruby's Test::Unit?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

Imagine I have a test like this:

```
class MyUnitTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_first
    # test code here
  end

  def test_second
    # test code here
  end

  def test_third
    # test code here
  end
end
```

My test cases are destructive, and I need to regenerate the input in between tests. Therefore, it would be useful to run only one test case at a time. Currently, my approach is to comment tests that I don't want executed, but surely there must be a better way?

So, for example, how do I run only `test_first` when I execute my test?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby Test::Unit Command line options?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543588/ruby-testunit-command-line-options)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `--name PATTERN` argument in order to filter out test names you want to run.

```
D:\Projects>ruby test.rb
Loaded suite test
Started
...
Finished in 0.000000 seconds.

3 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Test run options: --seed 39768

D:\Projects>ruby test.rb -n test_first
Loaded suite test
Started
.
Finished in 0.000000 seconds.

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Test run options: --seed 53891 --name "test_first"
```

Comment: Thank you! What did you use to search for this? I get only irrelevant results. Could you give me a link to this doc please?

Comment: I went to the ruby installation directory on my computer and opened minitest/unit.rb file. Then I searched for OptionParser usages - and found an answer. You can browse the code online: http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/lib/minitest/unit.rb?view=markup.

Comment: If you're on Ruby 1.8 (which has Test::Unit), or Ruby 1.9.2 or later, you can also do `ruby test.rb --help`. Unfortunately, an ordinary install of Ruby 1.9.1 doesn't give you anything when you do `ruby test.rb --help`.

Answer (score 2):

Can you regenerate the input with ruby? Then you could use the setup-method.

```
gem 'test-unit', '>= 2.1.1' #startup
require 'test/unit'

class Test_setup < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    #Your regeneration of the input
    puts "Setup"
  end

  def teardown
    #Clean actions
    puts "End"
  end

  def test_1()
    puts "Testing setup 1"
  end      
end
```

Comment: It's kind of error prone, since I'm relying on Mercurial's revert to regenerate. In the same time, I'm developing. It's kind of unsafe, I prefer to do it manually :)